# Thunderbird scripting from external software

Tags: java, c, thunderbird

I am trying to make a software that can automatically open search boxes in Thunderbird.

For example, I have a list of customer email-adresses in an external software. The software should be able to call Thunderbird and  search for emails of every client on that list.

Basically, I don't know where to start, and if that's possible. 
I know I could build a plugin for Thunderbird, but I need to call the searches from an external software.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird doesn't support scripting.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Calling_Thunderbird_from_other_programs

I think your options would be:

1. Create an extension, which perhaps can respond to calls from an external program (maybe listening on a port)
2. Read the thunderbird message database directly. I'm not sure how stable this would be if thunderbird is actually open, but it may be an option.
3. If you are
   using IMAP protocol, you could just search the mailserver instead of
   going to thunderbird.